# LaTeX in Spoilers

Tags: support

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: To be precise: 22897 bytes or 407048 pixels.]

It works fine without the `$$`s.

---

Additional details: I'm using Google Chrome 10.0.648.204 (not Chromium, so shut it :) ). The newest version is being installed as I write...

Comment: Alternatively to Moron's suggestions and more generally, put the latex in backticks (i.e. "`" without the quotes), to tell the engine not to interpret what follows as markup.

Comment: @Alex: This trick from math.MO doesn't work here. The backticks are reserved as code tags here, for instance `$\mathbb{R}$` was obtained by enclosing the LaTeX into backticks.

Comment: thanks for asking about this question. i've all but forgotten the spoiler feature!

Comment: @Theo Oh! Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\lt` and `\gt` instead of `<` and `>`. The parsing code might confuse them for html tags.

> The $\lt$ stands for $8$